# Eclipse turn off 'alert when export has warnings' feature?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I am working on a Java project in eclipse that has to be exported into a jar each time I need to test it.

There are plenty of warnings throughout the code, cannot be avoided.

When I export the jar I get this alert:
[image]

I do not need/want this alert, it's just a minor inconvenience to my workflow.
How can I turn it off?

Thanks

Comment: Don't you think that it's good thing to tell you about **your mistakes**? Just ignore it as you're ignoring these warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option to save a `build.xml` script that replicates what you are doing on the export.  If you do that, you can then just do show/view/ant and drag the `build.xml` in there and double click on the task to build it without errors.